# How to refer session variables in Groovy script in mule studio

Tags: mule

I just started working with Mule.
Flow description: 
I have an HTTP inbound endpoint receive XML message, and I Hvae to update the database (derby) using the XML payload.
Ex: I will be receiving Emp Id and Emp name, Exp in the request. I have to update the table with these values.

My Implementation:

After receiving XML input I am using the message Property transformer to save the values in Session scope.

```
 <message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Message Properties">    
    <add-message-property key="EmpNum"
                          value="#[xpath:/CreateEmployee/EmpNum]" /> 
 </message-properties-transformer>
```

like above. And then I have Groovy Script component to update the table.
My Query is:

```
r.update(conn, "INSERT INTO Employee values(#[header:session:EmpNum],#[header:session:EmpName],#[header:session:Experience],#[header:session:Role])");
```

But it is throwing error:

```
Lexical error at line 1, column 29.  Encountered: "#" (35), after : "". (org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException)
  org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException:-1 (null)
 Lexical error at line 1, column 29.  Encountered: "#" (35), after : "". Query: INSERT INTO Employee values(#[header:session:EmpNum],#[header:session:EmpName],#[header:session:Experience],#[header:session:Role]) Parameters: [](SQL Code: 30000, SQL State: + 42X02) (java.sql.SQLException)
  org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner:540 (null)
```

I have used a logger component to display the values.

```
#[header:session:EmpNum]
```

is displaying the proper value.

Please help me how to refer this session values in Groovy script?

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me when using Groovy script in Mule to read flow variables or session variables respectively.

For reading flow variables I'm using

```
message.getInvocationProperty('yourVarsName').toString()
```

For reading session variables I'm using

```
sessionVars['yoursVarsName'] or flowVars['yoursVarsName']
```

They work very well for me in the Groovy script in Mule 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Mule Expression Language (MEL) directly in a Groovy script.

If you're using Mule 3.3, replace `#[header:session:EmpName]` with `sessionVars('EmpName')` and similar with the other variables.

For previous versions, replace `#[header:session:EmpName]` with `message.getProperty('EmpName',PropertyScope.SESSION)`

Comment: Thanks for the response!. I tried your suggestion but no proper results. Here is the error I got.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the Groovy script to set the value before sending it as a SQL command. You are sending the literal "message.getProperty('Experience',PropertyScope.SESSION)" straight into the SQL command.

```
qr.update(conn, "INSERT INTO Employee values("+message.getProperty('EmpNum',PropertyScope.SESSION)+","+message.getProperty('EmpName',PropertyScope.SESSION)+","+message.getProperty('Experience',PropertyScope.SESSION)+","+message.getProperty('Role',PropertyScope.SESSION)+")")
```

Also don't forget to import the PropertyScope class in the script:

```
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#[groovy:message.getSessionProperty('sesVarValue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if any one if anyone needs the answer but for Mule 3.6+ I was able to access Sessions or flow variable by simply doing **sessionVars['sessVarName'] /flowVars['flowVarName']**

**DO NOT Forget to use "+" to concatenate Strings if values used as strings.